# Why is setTimeout acting synchronously?

Tags: javascript, task-queue, event-loop

Example of `setTimeout` being executed after a synchronous code is below it

```
console.log('hello');
setTimeout(() => console.log('timeout'), 0);
console.log('end');
```

Console Output:
    hello
    end
    timeout

Async:

```
function asyncForEach(array, callBack) {
    array.forEach(x => setTimeout(callBack(x), 0));
}
asyncForEach([1,2,3,4], (i) => console.log(i)); 
console.log('end');
```

Console Output:

```
1
2
3
4
end
```

Synchronous:

```
[1,2,3,4].forEach(x => console.log(x));
console.log('end');
```

Console output:

```
1
2
3
4
end
```

I am trying to better understand the `event loop` and the `task queue`, and after watching a well recommended video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) came across the semi statement of: "Callbacks can be synchronous and asynchronous". The speaker went on to demonstrate how the synchronous way would not end up going through the `task queue`, and therefore the `event loop`, so everything remained on the `stack`. However, the asynchronous way would cause the `task queue` to be populated with the eventual return of the `setTimeout` `callback`, which would make any synchronous below code executable since the `event loop` has to wait for an empty `stack` to insert the returned `callback`.

When running the above code (something I stole from him and also edited, so it could be a wrong addition on my part), the asynchronous way produces the same results as the synchronous way.

Could someone help explain why the asynchronous way does not act as the very first `setTimeout` example and/or provide explanation of how regular callbacks (such as the array helper methods) are not inserted into the `task queue` therefore never messed with by the `event loop`?

Comment: `setTimeout(callBack(x), 0)` This is calling the callback *immediately* and setting a timeout for whatever it returns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "asynchronous way" isn't asynchronous, because you called the function and passed its return value to `setTimeout`:

```
function asyncForEach(array, callBack) {
    array.forEach(x => setTimeout(callBack(x), 0)); // <-- callBack(x) calls callBack immediately
}
asyncForEach([1,2,3,4], (i) => console.log(i)); 
console.log('end');
```

If you want it delayed, make a function to pass to `setTimeout` that it can call later:

```
function asyncForEach(array, callBack) {
    array.forEach(x => setTimeout(() => callBack(x), 0)); // <-- Makes closure that calls callBack(x) later
}
asyncForEach([1,2,3,4], (i) => console.log(i)); 
console.log('end');
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug in your `asyncForEach` function. You're calling `callBack(x)` immediately and then passing the result of that function (`undefined`) to `setTimeout`.